# User permissions on volume drive

Tags: catalina, external-disk, permission, user-account

Connecting to my wireless volume external HD, there are 2 users listed for it, myself & "everyone". I have read/write access as admin, but "everyone" has "no access", and I can't change this. I'm guessing this is why my volume HD has just decided to not allow me any read/write access to it anymore as I 'don't have the necessary permission', even though no details have changed all week. After admin unlocking to change 'No access', it immediately reverts back to it. Need assistance with how to either remove "everyone", or change that to read/write access permanently.[image]

Comment: "wireless volume" ? Where is it & what is in charge of it? You will probably need to change perms there rather than locally. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnfgc.png for the kind of clues you should be looking for.

Comment: It's connected to my modem/router via USB, which I use 'Connect to Server' to access.

Comment: Then permissions need to be set on there. You can't override them locally, your Mac is not in charge of them, the remote server is.

Comment: It's just an external HD, it's not a remote server. WD 8TB My Book.

Comment: This also happened with a previous WD 10TB external HD I had, so I changed it up thinking it was the hard drive. Same problem has occured, so it's something my computer is struggling to understand.

Comment: Your first comment told me what I needed to know - it's connected to a remote device you have to use 'connect to server' to access. That means the remote device is in charge of the permissions, not your Mac. The Mac can do nothing at all about this situation. You must correct it on the remote device.

Comment: So I should be talking to WD instead of Apple for this one?

Comment: You should be looking up the manual for your modem/router. That's the 'server'. The HD is just a drive, it's not in charge of anything at all.

Comment: Aaah. Gotcha. Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

Try going into Terminal then `sudo chmod 777 /Volumes/ExternalDriveName` this should allow everyone access. If it doesn't work, then verify that it is formatted APFS, HFS, FAT32, or EXFAT. If it is formatted as NTFS, then it will be mounted as read only. If it is formatted as something that macOS can write to, then try running First Aid on the external disk. This might fix permissions. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Todd. Put in that coding into the terminal in every variation I could (volume name is 'volume(sda2)', without luck. First aid had to come to the rescue, but reset the HD in the process - so starting the file transfer again!

Comment: If this answer was correct, then can you please mark it as the correct answer. Glad to hear that it worked!